# Want to insert data in oracle table from 2nd row of a text file in php

Tags: php, oracle

i want to insert data in oracle database from a text file. The first row of text file contains the header. i want to skip the first line. Below is my code.

```
for($i =1;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE; $i++) {
// The query uses placeholders for data
$sql_insert = oci_parse($conn, 'insert into auto_debit_data_input (input_id,req_by,company_name) values (auto_debit_input_id_seq.nextval,:req_by,:company_name)');
                oci_bind_by_name($sql_insert, ':req_by', $data[0]);
                oci_bind_by_name($sql_insert, ':company_name', $data[0]);           
                $result=oci_execute($sql_insert);
                if (!$result) {
                    $errmsg="No Data inserted. Please check all field";
                    //exit;
                   }
}
```

Below is my file data.

```
REQ_BY,Name
Mr X, Bangladesh
Mr Y, India
```

My code inserting from the header of the file. But i want to insert from 2nd line. Please help me to fix this.

I have also tried using below line but no luck.

```
for($i =2;($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE; $i++)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following line at first place of you loop (if you are starting from `$i = 1`):

```
if($i==1){
    continue;
}
```

Not tested, But Hope It will work;

**Logic:**
Skip the first iteration of loop...:)